# Can NSPredicate Compare a Property to an Array of Wildcards?

Tags: swift, objective-c, nspredicate

I need an NSPredicate that compares a property to an array of wildcards. Something like...

```
NSArray *collection = @[@"Jerry*",@"George*",@"Elaine*"];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"property LIKE IN %@", collection];
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Try with just `IN` - Refer - https://nspredicate.xyz/#is-included-in-an-array-of-values.

Comment: How are you going to use the predicate, in a Core Data fetch?

Comment: Have you tried constructing the predicate in code with `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"property LIKE %@", string]` and `NSCompoundPredicate`?

Comment: @Ananth using just IN will search the collection but not for wildcard values. Property, for example, might be "Jerry S", "George C" or "Elaine B" and I want to match those.

Comment: @Willeke No, this is not Core Data, just filtering an array of objects. Regarding NSCompoundPredicate I did end up going that route. I had to iterate my wildcard items to build the compounds but it seems the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `NSCompoundPredicate` to get this done. I was hoping there was a shorter route but it's fairly painless.

```
NSArray *collection = @[@"Jerry*",@"George*",@"Elaine*"];
NSMutableArray *thePredicateArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
        
for (id *theItem in collection)
   {
   [thePredicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"property LIKE %@",theItem]];
   }    
    
NSCompoundPredicate *theCompoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:thePredicateArray];
```